# Passing a method as a parameter to another method in the same class

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int foo(int func) {
        func();
    }

    int bar() {
    }


    int faz() {
    }
};
```

I know the above is incorrect, I'm not exactly sure how to represent what I'm trying to do. But I want to be able to pass in other methods like `bar` or `faz` as parameters into `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pointer to a class method, and then invoke it on `this`, eg:

```
class A {
public:
    int foo(int (A::*func)()) {
        return (this->*func)();
    }

    int bar() {
        return ...;
    }

    int faz() {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

```
A a:
a.foo(&A::bar);
a.foo(&A::faz);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question with an example as much as possible. I hope it will help you a bit.

```
class A {
public:
void functionSample()
{
    // ...
}

void callFunctionSample(void (A::*functionPointer)())
{
    (this->*functionPointer)();
}
};

int main()
{
    A obj;

    obj.callFunctionSample(&A::functionSample);

    return 0;
}
```

To pass sampleFunction() as parameter into another class member function, you can use pointer for the member function. In callFunctionSample, void (A::*functionPointer)() ensures that you take a member function from the class A as a parameter.

(this->*functionPointer)(); ensures that the member function, sampleFunction(), is invoked upon the call of the callSampleFunction(...) by obj, the object of the class.